# Can you tell me the relationships and differences between Vi and Vim

Tags: vim, vi, text-editor

I often see Vim in my lab, but I also know Vi, but I never have a chance to use it, I search for it by using google, but I can't get a website to download Vi. Can you show me the relationships and differences between Vi and Vim, if possible, give me a url to download the Vi. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite what others have said, Vim is *not* an enhanced version of Vi, nor is it an extension. It might seem that way because Vim was designed to be, by default, as compatible with Vi as possible (even more so in Vi-compatible mode). Obtaining Vi source code used to required a Unix source code license, and since additional features were desired, Vim was developed *independently of Vi*. It is more properly called a clone, which has additional features.

Vim is the standard editor on many *nix systems. The "program" `vi` is often just a symlink to `vim`. Historical interests aside, I can't think of a compelling argument for using Vi. Vim is much more modern, and any features you don't want can be disabled, or support for them not compiled in.

You can download the source for vi here: http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you,I really appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2):

Vim is an enhanced version of Vi with extra features. If you know how to use Vi, you won't have trouble using Vim, since you know the basics. Sometimes people used to Vim have trouble with Vi as it doesn't have all the extra features as Vim.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has an option called `compatible` that makes vim behave nearly exactly like vi. See `:help 'compatible` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

VIM is Vi iMproved. VIM is basically an extension of Vi. I would learn VIM not Vi as it just gets too hard for many things. The advantage is if you can use Vim you can use Vi, just the extra snazzy stuff like syntax highlighting etc will be missing.

See wikipedia for more details on the history of the two: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)

Here is a good guide to Vi including how to install for your distro: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html